# Why doesn't connect() function see Slot?

Tags: c++, qt

I have two classes named as Snake and MainClass. I need to use thread. For using thread I have to use Signal/Slot connect() function. But this function didn't connect to SLOT. I don't understand why.
You can find a small piece of my code(related part) below

```
MainClass.h
public:
   Snake *snake;
```

```
MainClass.cpp

QThread *thread1 = new QThread();

snake = new Snake();

snake->moveToThread(thread1);

connect(thread1, SIGNAL(started()), snake, SLOT(keyPressEvent(event)));

thread1->start();
```

```
Snake.h
class Snake : public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Snake();

public slots:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
```

```
Snake.cpp
    void Snake::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Left)
    {
       qDebug()<<"player1";
    }
}
```

```
main.cpp
MainClass *mainclass = new MainClass();
mainclass->show();
mainclass->game();
```

Game works before connect() is added. But when I add connect(), I see an error:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot Snake::keyPressEvent() in ..\YilanOyun\mainclass.cpp:62"
```

Comment: `connect(thread1, SIGNAL(started()), snake, SLOT(keyPressEvent(event)));` what is `event` here? / How do you expect it to be populated?

Comment: I do not see the logic in connecting the signal that indicates that the thread was started with the method that handles keyboard events. I think you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Please stop using the old `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros. Use the modern, member function based, compile time checked, signal/slot connect functions instead. They are faster and you get errors at compile time rather than run time when you mess something up.

Comment: Is this `Qt4.X`?

Comment: On the other hand Snake that is a QGraphicsRectItem and consequently is part of the GUI should not be moved to another thread, which reinforces my previous comment: you have an XY problem.

Comment: All of the above needs to be clarified, why is it necessary for Snake to be moved in another thread?

Comment: I am writting a multiple snake game. My first player's snake is running perfectly but when I add second snake for player2, I have to use thread for controlling two snakes at same time. I searched about thread, I found this signal/slot way. I think it is appropriate for my goal. But I cant work it. keyPressedEvent function didnt go to another class as Slot. I can share all code but it is very long. So i shared just a pieces of them in order to tell my problem. By the way I am using Qt 4.10.1.

Comment: @Magic_Key "I have to use thread for controlling two snakes at same time" - No You don't. You can easily do that in a single threaded program.

Comment: @Magic_Key Research "state machine".

Comment: @Jasper Juhl actually you are right. Player1 snakes already works but player2 snake is still waiting and dont take a command. I can use one thread only for snake2 but I think I need to use connect() again. Could you tell me another way except using connect?

Comment: @Magic_Key You do not need to use threads, everything can be executed in the same thread (unless you have a heavy task that until now I do not see it), in general a state machine is enough. I still think you have an XY problem

Comment: @Magic_Key You are probably using Qt Creator 4.10.1, the IDE, but you are using a version Qt (the framework) that is either 4.8.x or 5.x?

Comment: @rubenvb it is Qt 4.10.1 open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QThread started signal does not have any arguments but you are connecting it to a KeyPressEvent thats taking a KeyEvent argument thats why it says it cannot find a slot that takes no argument. Slot and signal signature should match.

Comment: You are perfect. What if I create a new function and I call my keyPressedEvent into it? For example void newFunction {keyPressedEvent() ... } I can add newFunction to my SLOT because it takes no arguments and then maybe my problem will be solved. Am I right?

Comment: What do you want to achieve when the thread starts? Or do you want to trigger the thread to start on the keypressEvent?

Comment: @Magic_Key Although the superficial connection problem is solved, you have a fundamental problem: You should not move Snake to another thread. Read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread

Comment: There are two snakes. One of them is playing with direction button, other one is playing with "w,a,s,d". I can use snake1. If I change the object definition order, I can use snake2. what I am saying is that two snakes are working but just only one snake work at the same time. Program doesnt work two objects. If I use thread, I can take keyPressedEvent for two snakes. Thread is not related with buttons. I just want to give permisson for object in turn.  If I trigger thread via button, it makes a problem because maybe player2 never press a button just wait and watch player1.

Comment: @Magic_Key Mmm, have you read what an XY problem is? If you have not done so then I recommend you read the link that I have provided in one of my comments. You probably have another error that causes only one snake to work and the other not, but unfortunately the code you provide does not evidence that. My recommendation is that you ask: **How to work with 2 or more Snakes at the same time? and then provide your [mre]**, so we focus on the real problem (problem X): "How to work with several snakes?" and not with the problem Y: "how to connect a slot to keyPressEvent"

Comment: My solution would be that when you are creating each snake you assign it an id like 1 and the other 2 then have a slot which receives a keyPressEvent connected to the mainWindow and then in your slot just check the snake id to determine which controls are valid.

Comment: @Magic_Key I'm not humiliating you (and sorry if I did), but since you are a beginner that implies not knowing how the tool works completely (in this case Qt) you have a small perspective that causes the XY problem, but we who We already suffer that problem. We want to take you on the right path. An XY problem occurs when the OP asks about a solution that nobody guarantees will work instead of the real problem, and it seems to me that this is your case.

Comment: @Magic_Key [cont.] If you want to know why the connection cannot be made: The signatures of the started signal do not match the keyPressEvent method, but the underlying problem is that the XEvent methods should not be invoked through a signal or directly but through events. To make it clearer your connection is equivalent to saying: when the thread starts, the started signal will be emitted that will invoke the keyPressEvent method that the keyboard event should receive, but what event? Was any key pressed? Well, no. Don't you think it's illogical? Bye

Comment: @Update I searched Thread and Event class. keyPressEvent funtion cant be a SLOT because event is like signal and it doesnt need Thread. Because when event comes, it works automatically. So I moved my keyPressEvent into my main class and I took the neccessary keyboard button via this function. Now my program will work. Thank you for your inspirational answer.